# SSH from mainland China to google compute engine VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is it able to ssh to google compute engine virtual machines from mainland China directly (there is no direct access to any google websites)? If the line is unstable or blocked, can we get a good user experience by deploying a proxy server in Hong Kong or some accessible data center in US ?

Comment: The answer depends on details not in your question. Where are you connecting from? What type of Internet in China (home or business, public or VPN). If a business, do you have the required licenses? What is running on the VM (website)? Are financial transactions involved (credit cards)? These are all factors that are affected by government restrictions on Internet traffic. As the answer below states, Google does not restrict traffic, but you still have to get your traffic onto Google's backbone.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Platform do not have any restriction on the traffic coming from China.

By looking at your comment, it seems like you are experiencing some issues while accessing Google Cloud Platform products from within
mainland China. It might be caused by networking conditions
in China, rather than Google's own services.

If you required any technical assistance with this issue, you could contact one of Google's [Technological partners](https://cloud.google.com/partners/technology-partners)

Our transparency report found [here](http://www.google.com/transparencyreport/traffic/) may also be useful:

Note: If you are interested in setting up any workload connected with Google Cloud Platform in [Hong Kong region](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/gcps-region-in-hong-kong-is-now-open), you may also use [**this help**](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/hongkong/) center article. As per the article, the Hong Kong cloud region currently offers services like compute, storage, security & networking. These services can be used alongside with various other Google Cloud Platform products(or any compatible outside products) according to your purpose/needs.